# Why do you use a Scope Resolution Operator when defining a class' method?

Tags: c++, scope, scope-resolution-operator

My question about the Scope Resolution Operator (::) is why do we use it in a CPP file to define the methods of a class? I'm more so asking about the SRO itself, rather than the relationship between CPP and Header files.

Comment: How would you want to define method in cpp else?

Comment: Let's say a cpp file has two classes `A` and `B` both of them have a method `func` and a global function named `func` without scope resolution how'd you define class `A` and `B`'s `func` function?

Comment: Yes, the name of the class is part of the function name.  Without it, the compiler doesn't know which class you are referring to.  That's not the case in the class definition though, because the function name appears within `class Foo {` ... `};`.

Comment: minor nitpick on style: "you" and "we" can make a question unclear. "I" dont have to use the scope resolution operator when defining a method: `struct foo { void bar() {} };`. it would be more clear to show what you mean instead of assuming that "you" and "we" already know what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a class:

```
struct foo {
    void bar() {}
};
```

Then the full name of `bar` is `::foo::bar`. The leading `::` to refer to the global namespace can often be omitted. There is no `bar` in the global namespace, hence `bar` alone (or `::bar`) does not name an entity and when you define the method out of line you need to tell what `bar` you mean:

```
 struct foo { 
       void bar();
 };
 struct baz {
       void bar();
 };

 void bar() {}    // this defines a completely unrelated free function called bar

 void foo::bar() {} // defines foo::bar
 void baz::bar() {} // defines baz::bar
```

You need the scope resolution operator to state which method you want to define.

For more details I refer you to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup